# jquery lightbox group images

Tags: jquery, lightbox

i use such lightbox http://www.leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ here is example of using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Use this example, or...
    $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(); // Select all links that contains lightbox in the attribute rel
    // This, or...
    $('#gallery a').lightBox(); // Select all links in object with gallery ID
    // This, or...
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
    // This, or...
    $('a').lightBox(); // Select all links in the page
    // ... The possibility are many. Use your creative or choose one in the examples above
});
</script>
```

i want to group images, so i write url like this `<a href='' rel='lightbox[group1]'></a>` and `<a href='' rel='lightbox[group2]'></a>`

how i run this? `$('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();` not work, or may be anothe method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have HTML tags like this:

`<a href='' rel='group1'></a>` and `<a href='' rel='group2'></a>`

You can use this:

`$('a[@rel=group1]').lightBox();` and `$('a[@rel=group2]').lightBox();`

Answer (score 4):

I've found simple solution if you have a lot of pictures, you don't have to add rel to each. Just surround images with div with class e.g. lightbox-group

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="lightbox-group" id="first">
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>

<div class="lightbox-group" id="second">
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.lightbox-group').each(function(){
        $(this).find('a').lightBox();                     
     });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just write `rel=lightbox` in your all image group

and try with

```
      $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
```

see **[Here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

> **jQuery('[attribute*="value"]') : **
>   Selects elements that have the
>   specified attribute with a value
>   containing the a given substring.

Comment: but what about grouping images? this will put all images together

Comment: if you want another group then try with different`rel`

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the plugin like [here](http://fatlabmusic.com/blog/2009/01/07/how-to-modify-jquery-lightbox-plugin-to-use-image-sets/comment-page-1/#comment-578). It's quite simple, but works like a charm.